# I am really confused about Git Branches

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am coming from a TFS background with everything stored in SQL Server.  I am now in a situation of using GIT through DevOps for managing code.  There are several things that I am very confused about.

So lets say I go into DevOps via the web browser and I see the default branch (i.e. Master).  Now I go into Visual Studio 2019 and I say new branch based on Master and I give it the name QA_6.5.3_George.

The branch appears to be created and I have the code but I don't see that branch in DevOps.  When you create a branch like this is it only local until you push it up?

Then, supposed I wanted to clean up branched I created:

I click on the Git Repository Explore in Visual Studio and I see the following:

[image]

I only want to delete my local branches.  How do I know which of these are branches I created and which are not mine?  I just find this very confusing.  I have found documentation on HOW to delete branches etc.  I just don't understand what is going on under the covers with Git regarding 'ownership' and location of branches.

FYI I am looking to understand this in the context of Azure DevOps and Visual Studio 2019

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:  So here is an actual example of what I am trying to understand:**

Here is my DevOps server showing I have no branches for a project other than the master:

[image]

However in Visual Studio I see I have a branch based on 6.5.2.

[image]

What I am trying to understand is why I don't see my QA_6_5_3_George branch in DevOps?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a tutorial on git basic concepts. What terms did you use when you tried to search for an answer?

Comment: Git branches don't have owners. (Some hosting sites *add* concepts of "protection" to various branch names, but that's not part of Git.) In fact, branch *names*, in Git, are unimportant and you should not be very concerned with them at all *except* in that *humans* (not Git) use the branch names to *find* particular important-to-the-human commits. Git is really all about the *commits*.

Comment: A Git repository is a collection of commits. The commits themselves are numbered, with magic "hash IDs" (or Object IDs, OIDs, to be formal). These numbers appear random and are very difficult for humans to use. So a repository also includes a separate table of *names*, such as branch and tag names; these names help the human user of Git find commit hash IDs so that Git can find the commits. (*Git* needs the raw hash ID.) If you no longer find a name useful to find commits, you are free to delete that name: you will simply no longer be able to find those commits.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to retain the ability to find the commits, keep the *name* around. Keep a branch or tag name as long as it's useful to *you*. Drop it when it's no longer useful to *you*. That's basically all there is here.

Comment: In the image you included, the bolded branch is the branch you are currently on (always a local branch).  The branches under `remotes/origin` which have that little blue icon are the remote branches (specifically for the remote `origin`).  All other branches are local branches (and therefore deleting them will not affect anybody else).

Comment: And - to add to @AndrewMcClement's note - a *remote-tracking name* is not (well, not exactly) a *branch* name. It's your Git repository's way of remembering the branch names *as seen in some other Git repository*. Whenever you run `git fetch origin`, your Git software sees *all their branch names* and will create or update your `origin/*` remote-tracking names based on their *branch* names. You don't have to (and generally should not) do anything about any of these.

Comment: @AndrewMcClement So everything not under remotes/origin is local?  Is everything in the release folder local also so I can delete it without changing anything on the server?  I believe the big question I asked 'When I create a branch - where is it created' has not been answered.  I am looking for something like ‘serve only’, ‘locally only’ or ‘both on the server and locally’.  If it is only locally, is it the Push process that will put the branch on the server?

Comment: 1st question: yes

2nd question: yes

3rd question: When you create a branch, it is only a local branch.  Nothing has changed on the server.


4th question: TLDR yes.  When you push the branch for the first time (using Visual Studio) it will create a branch on the remote and set that as the upstream branch for your local branch.  At this point (say you started with local branch `solaris`) you would now see a branch `remotes/origin/solaris`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I think, is where your confusion comes in: Git is a *distributed* version control system in which *every user gets a **copy** of every repository.*  A Git repository consists mainly<sup>1</sup> of two databases, one usually much larger than the other:

- The larger database holds commits and other internal Git objects.  These objects are numbered: each one has a very large, random-looking number, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), which Git calls an *object ID* or less formally, a *hash ID*.  These numbers are the same in *every copy* of the repository: that is, if your copy has an object with hash ID `9c897eef06347cc5a3eb07c3ae409970ab1052c8`, and some other repository has an object with that same hash ID, those are the *same object*.

  Git needs these numbers to access the objects.  But obviously it's hard to memorize `9c897eef06347cc5a3eb03c3ae409970ab1052c8`.  Is that even the same number I quoted just a moment ago?  (It's not.  See if you can see which character I changed.)  Therefore, each repository carries a second database: a table that maps *names* to hash IDs.
- The smaller database is this names table.  In here you'll find your branch names, your tag names, and your remote-tracking names, among other names.  Each name maps to just one hash ID: this means that you can type in a branch name, like `master` or `main` or `QA_6.5.3_George` and have *Git itself* look up the right hash ID.

By using names instead of numbers, you can keep yourself from having to memorize hash IDs.  But here's where we have to be careful: a *branch name* is not a *branch*, except when the person saying *branch* means *branch name*.  (For a humorous way to remember the difference between a thing and its name, see [the Wikipedia article on Haddock's Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks%27_Eyes).  For more on the distinction in Git, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

When you clone a repository, you get all of the *commits* (and supporting objects), and you get *no branch names at all*.  Then, having cloned the repository, your Git software will create *one* branch name in your repository.  You can use this branch name, or any of the *remote-tracking names*, to create more branch names; or you can use any Git commit hash ID to create a branch name.  The *hash IDs* are what *Git* cares about.  The branch names exist for *your* purposes.

Again, the cloning process copies only the *commits* (and other Git objects) database, not the *names* database.  This means that *all* of your branch names are local.  Even your remote-tracking names are local: they're your software-and-repository local *memory* of some other repository's *branch* names.

When you run `git push`, you have your Git software connect to some other Git software.  Your Git software reads from your Git repository.  Their software reads from, and potentially writes to, their repository.  Your Git can see their branch names (and other names) here and their hash IDs, and your Git can offer *commits* to their Git.

Your Git—your software working with your repository—will now offer, to their Git (their software working with their repository), any new commits you have made, that they do not yet have.  This all works by *hash ID*.  Because the hash IDs are unique, and match if and only if the two repositories have the same actual *commits*, your Git can easily tell if some commit that you have is or is not the same as some commit they have.  So any new *commits* you made can be sent over, without having to re-send the existing commits.

Once your Git is done sending over your new *commits* (as needed), your Git now *asks* their Git to *create or update* one of *its* branch names in *its* branch-and-other-names database.  If they obey this polite request, your Git will also create or update your corresponding remote-tracking name.

For instance, suppose you create a new-to-you branch-name `george-ceaser`.  Let's assume further that *they* do not have this same branch name.

Whether or not you make any new *commits* on this branch, you then run `git push origin george-ceaser` so that your Git calls up their Git and:

- sends any new commits you made (if any), then
- asks them to create or update a branch named `george-ceaser` in *their* Git.

If they obey this polite request, they now have a branch-name `george-ceaser`, and your Git will create `origin/george-ceaser` to remember the same hash ID that you just had them remember under the name `george-ceaser`.  Now you and they have "the same branch", as humans will put it—but in fact, they have *their own* name `george-ceaser`, and *you* have *your own* name `george-ceaser`.  These are two different names that merely happen to be spelled the same!

You may *delete* your `george-ceaser` at any time.  Once you're done with it, you should delete it.  That won't affect *their* `george-ceaser` at all: that one is *their* name.  Should you wish to ask them to delete *their* `george-ceaser`, you would do this with:

```
git push origin --delete george-ceaser
```

which sends to them a polite request that *they* delete *their* branch name `george-ceaser`.  If they obey this polite request, *nothing happens in your Git*.  If they refuse this polite request, *nothing happens in your Git*.

(Again, by "your Git" I mean "your software operating on your repository".)

Now and then, it's wise to run `git fetch origin --prune`.  This has your Git call up their Git, list out all their branch names, and then—because of the `--prune`—your Git will *remove* from *your* repository any `origin/*` name that exists in your repository, but for which *their* **branch** name is now gone.<sup>2</sup>  Usually though, you'll know whether you've made `george-ceaser` in *their* repository, and if and when you delete the name `george-ceaser` in your own repository, you will know whether you want to ask them to delete the name `george-ceaser` in *their* repository.

**You will find this confusing for some time.**  It is fundamentally confusing to humans, who don't handle clones very well.  We think clones are exact copies, but they aren't; then we make changes to the copies, and we can't remember which copy we changed; and then we get mixed up about who has what and it gets messy.  Just remember that the idea behind Git is that *everyone gets a copy*.  You make changes to *your* copy, after which you may (but are not required to) use `git push` to send *your new commits* to some *other* copy, and then ask them to create or update one of their *branch* names to remember your new commits.

In some cases, you may end up using `git push --force-with-lease` or `git push --force` to change the last step of `git push` from "polite request" to "forceful command".  That is, instead of asking the other Git *Please, if it's OK, create or update your `george-ceaser`* you can send *I command you to create or update your `george-ceaser`!*  They're allowed to reject the command, but they're more likely to obey a command, even if it's harmful, than they are to obey a polite request even if it's harmful.  So be (much) more careful when using `--force` or `--force-with-lease`.  Git tries harder not to do anything harmful when you use the polite-request form.

---

<sup>1</sup>Most repositories also offer a *working area*, and the repositories you use will be like this.

<sup>2</sup>I personally like this behavior enough to set `fetch.prune` to true, so that every `git fetch` does it, but there are a few sharp edges here and there in Git where this may unexpectedly delete some remote-tracking name, so you might want to do it only at carefully-chosen times until you're much more familiar with this.